# How to enable http2 on CentOS7 with Apache 2.4.46

Tags: apache, server, webserver, http2

I have CentOS 7, with Apache 2.4.46. I have done pretty much every thing available on internet. I am getting the below error

> The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm
> determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more
> demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not
> do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work,
> but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.

My apache is running from /usr/local/apache2/.

I have seen, I may need to use php-fpm module to run this.

I have made changes on my live server and It is kinda stuck now. Though work impact is very less but I really want to learn what wrong am I doing

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide more information. So far we know that you did _"something"_ (as in "everything available on the internet") and could only tell you to do _"something else"_ (this time literally). Also note [help/on-topic] and the [tag:apache] tag description. This doesn't seem to be about programming, but about configuration. Questions of this kind would be off topic on stackoverflow, with a better fit on superuser.com or serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to:

- Disable mod_mpm_prefork
- Disable mod_php (disable the php module, what ever it's named, example: libphp7)
- Enable mod_mpm_event
- Enable mod_http2
- Enable mod_proxy
- Enable mod_proxy_fcgi
- Enable mod_setenvif
- Install PHP-FPM using `yum install php-fpm`, or you might need to specify the version `yum install php7-fpm` or `php8-fpm`, and then start the PHP-FPM service after installation of that, using `systemctl start php-fpm` or `php7-fpm`/`php8-fpm`.
- Add the following to Apache configuration:

  ```
  <FilesMatch "*\.php">
     SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://localhost:9000"
  </FilesMatch>
  ```

  If it is running as an UNIX socket, you would need to change it to:

  ```
  <FilesMatch "*\.php">
     SetHandler "proxy:unix:/path/to/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost:9000"
  </FilesMatch>
  ```
- Restart Apache